# MVC @Html.Action with both routing and model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, html-helper

I'm needing to call @Html.Action with both routing information and a model.
For example, this is what I need to do:

```
@Html.Action("Header", "PageHeader", @LayoutModel, new { Area = "Common" })
```

There is an overload for either routing values or model but not both.

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, played around until I found the answer

```
@Html.Action("Header", "PageHeader", new { Area = "Common", headerModel = @LayoutModel })
```

I just included the model I wanted to send in the object that I used for routing. All is good now.